# IAM permission for user to only view their own instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I want to define an IAM User that can view and access only their own instance and not another one.

I have created a user root to control users and control instance EC2 but I can not define a user account that can access only their own instance.

How to do this?

Comment: Have you tried? What is your code?

Comment: When you say "view and access" do you mean the user can only view his own instance in the console?

Comment: What permissions do you want to give the user? Can you clarify what you mean by "view and access"? Do you mean view in the Amazon EC2 console? By access, do you mean SSH/RDP into the instance itself? Please Edit your question to add more details so we can provide a suitable answer. Thank you.

Comment: WarrenG: Thank for your response and Yes "view and access" I mean the user can only view and use his own instance in the console. I want to give permission to user can use only own instance such as SSH/RDP.

Comment: John Rotenstein yes. view I mean can see only own instance in console and access I mean Can SSH only own instance.

Answer (score 0):

EC2 login and AWS console login are different accounts. If I understood correctly, you want to restrict your console user from accessing a machine that's launched by some other user. You can restrict this through IAM policy using instance tags. [Refer here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_iam-tags.html) You might need to add tags on each instance creation. Then you need to edit user's IAM policy and allow EC2 actions as per the document. For example, you have 2 users foo and bar. When foo launches an instance, he adds a tag with value 'foo'. Also, foo already has an IAM policy attached, which allows him to access EC2 instance with the specific tag and value 'foo'.

PS: Not all EC2 actions can be restricted through resource tags.

Comment: Example If I create 2 user, user1 and user2. when they login to console they can see their instance in the console. Than what I want to control is I want user1 can see only own instance in console when login and user2 can see own instance in console too . what can I do ?

Comment: @SopheaktraVuth you cannot do that. ec2:ListInstances doesn’t support resource tags. Please accept as answer if this answers your query.

Comment: Munavir Chavody So Can I manage user by allow user1 can use only own instance and can not use user2 instance?

Comment: What do you mean by using an instance? To RDP or SSH the instance? You won’t be able to using IAM users. IAM users are different from server login.

Comment: use instance I mean to can SSH only own instance and when login to use IAM can see only own instance too.

Comment: This is JSON I tried {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:ap-northeast-1a:283316032427:instance/i-0f40388eabbad2f32"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/Owner": "Sopheaktra"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, IAM user can not login to an EC2 instance. You can’t manage os level permissions using IAM. Only some actions supports resource tags so everyone can view all instances.

Comment: So can you give me some advice to manage account that can see only own instance created in console ?

Comment: You cannot achieve that since IAM doesn’t support it. Also you cannot use IAM user to login to servers. Please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to control the EC2 console view where all the instances are showing created by multiple users then it is not possible. But if you are trying to control the access of instances like stop, start, terminate then you can do that using tag-based policies  [Reference](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-policy-tags-restrict/)